# How to solve "incompatible target" when linking library with Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I want to link a library that I have compiled for arm using the Android NDK compiler, with an Android project. But when compiling I get the following error:

```
/home/android/android-ndk-r9/sources/libraryname/android/arm/lib/libname.so: 
    incompatible target
```

I am using the same compiler for the library and the project I am linking with. What am I doing wrong here?

The library is built with the following script:

```
NDK=/home/android/android-ndk-r9
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
./configure \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
make clean
make
make install
```

This is an objdump from the compiled library:

```
xa.o:     file format elf32-i386
rw-r--r-- 0/0  47720 Aug  3 03:22 2014 xa.o
```

This is an objdump from a library that works with NDK:

```
libopentut_la-functionalRegression.o:     file format elf32-little
rw-r--r-- 0/0 206612 Aug  3 03:22 2014 libopentut_la-functionalRegression.o
```

Comment: Trying to do this by hand is just asking for trouble - you really should use the NDK build system or its stand alone toolchain capability, or at least try to dump out the settings it is using (`ndk-build V=1`) or compare the resulting files with objdump or similar.

Answer (score 0):

**IF YOU ARE USING ANDROID STUDIOS**

Make sure in your `build.gradle` you don't also have another abi that you don't need.

For example if my library `.so` file is only for 32-bit and I have something like

```
ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
```

in my `build.gradle` it will fail with this error.